# Add a character to each vector in a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a list of character vectors:

```
vector.list <- list("cytidine", "uridine", "dihydrouridine", "2'-O-methylcytidine")
```

I want to add a the character "30" to each vector in this list, resulting in:

```
vector.list
[[1]]
[1] "30"       "cytidine"

[[2]]
[1] "30"      "uridine"

[[3]]
[1] "30"             "dihydrouridine"

[[4]]
[1] "30"                  "2'-O-methylcytidine
```

I know how to do this with a "for loop" or by writing a function and using lapply. For example:

```
for (i in 1:length(vector.list)){
vector.list[[i]] <- c("30", vector.list[[i]])
}
```

However, I need to do this for many combinations of vector lists and characters and I want this code to be accessible to other people. I was wondering if there was a more elegant command for adding a character to each vector in a list of vectors in R?

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(vector.list, append, "30", after=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(vector.list,
       function(x) c("30", x))
```